# use of static keyword

Tags: apex

```
Public Class Example
{
  public static Integer a;
  public integer b;
  public Example()
{
  a=10;
  b=10;
}
public void add()
{
  a=a+10;
  b=b+10;
  System.debug('a value is '+a);
  System.debug('b value is '+b);
}
}
```

in the anonymous class

```
Example e1= new Example();
e1.add();
Example e2= new Example();
e2.add();
```

if i get the same result for a and b then what is use of static keyword?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're calling the constructor twice. The constructor is setting the value of `a` back to 10 each time. Every time the constructor is called, it wipes out whatever was there before. Static means there's only one copy, not that the copy can't be used over and over again. Here's how you would have correctly initialized `a`:

```
public class Example { 
public static Integer a;
public Integer b;
static { // initialize static variables once
    a = 10;
}
public Example() {
    b = 10;
}
public void add() {
    a += 10;
    b += 10;
    System.debug('a is '+a);
    System.debug('b is '+b);
}
```

This results in logs that would look like:

```
a is 20
b is 20
a is 30
b is 20
```

Assuming you used the following code:

```
Example e1= new Example(); e1.add(); Example e2= new Example(); e2.add();
```

Alternatively, you would have gotten the "correct" results if you re-ordered your code:

```
Example e1 = new Example(), e2 = new Example();
e1.add(); 
e2.add();
```

Which would have the identical output as the prior example given the corrected version of the code.

The moral of the story here: do not initialize static variables in instance constructors without careful consideration of the consequences. There are legitimate reasons for doing so (e.g. singletons, ref-counts, etc), but you should understand why it is necessary before you do so.